# Постоянный доступ приложения к микрофону на Android 11

Tags: android, android-permissions

Как, не используя Root, предоставить приложению доступ к микрофону на Android 11 (Redmi 10) (не только во время его использования)? В настройках такого пункта попросту нет. Решение через ADB подойдёт, однако приветствуются более простые пути :)
Я, разумеется, лез в настройки приложения, однако конкретно у разрешения «Микрофон» нужного пункта не нашлось.

[image: (Скриншот)]

Comment: Скорее всего никак: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/permissions